# How to invoke an controller action in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, highcharts

I am rendering charts(based on highcharts) using ember. I want to invoke a function on clicking a point. I have defined this function inside my ember component. See jsfiddle link below:

```
{}   http://jsfiddle.net/qmmvx/67/
```

On clicking a point, I get an error which indicates App.ChartComponent is null.What is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if using `App.__container__.lookup` here is the smartest way, but replacing `App.ChartComponent.test();` with `App.__container__.lookup('component:chart').send('test')` solves your problem. `send` is used to invoke any method from `actions`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I was also able to get it working by placing my function inside the component instead of the controller.But I have another question. If you notice,in this example  http://jsfiddle.net/qmmvx/2/  , the controller action is invoked using App.graphController. So how does this work ? Also what are pros and cons in populating data using Ember component vs Ember controller? Which is the right way to go about. I am sorry for too many questions, I am newbie to ember.

Comment: In your fiddle you use controller's method instead of action. That's not a mistake. Using actions is a good practice if you refer to them from the template - so you won't have to specify `target` parameter for `{{action}}` helper (for example, `{{action myAction target="controller"}}` - to use controller's `myAction` method). And so, if you do this in component's template, you should define action in the component, and in the controller if you use it in the template corresponding to this controller.